# I need help adding a button to perform this HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I need help to add my HTML code to a button.
For example, when I press the button, my code starts.

```js
function progressBarSim(al) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = al + "%";
    bar.value = al;
    al++;
    var sim = setTimeout("progressBarSim(" + al + ")", 300);
    if (al == 100) {
        status.innerHTML = "100%";
        bar.value = 100;
        clearTimeout(sim);
        var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
        finalMessage.innerHTML = "Process is complete";
    }
}
var amountLoaded = 0;
progressBarSim(amountLoaded);
```

```html
<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
<span id="status"></span>
<h1 id="finalMessage"></h1>
```

Comment: Put the code in your question by [edit]ing it. Use a code block to format it. Read the editor's help if you don't know how to.

Comment: Done & Thanks too!

Answer (score 0):

These are two different things: html code & scripting code. So I think it is better to behave differently with each of them. I guess you want to show progress bar when a button is clicked. If I'm right, then you can wrap **progress bar html code** with a **div** tag and set its **display** style to **none** - `<div style="display:none">...</div>`. Then add all script in a function e.x. `startProgress` and add one line of code at top of your function to change div **display** style to **block**. It must look something like this:

```
<div id="divProgbar" style="display:none">
    <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress> <span id="status"></span> <h1 id="finalMessage"></h1>
</div>
<script>
function startProgress(){
document.getElementById('divProgbar').style.display='block';
function progressBarSim(al) {
  var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.innerHTML = al+"%";
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
 var sim = setTimeout("progressBarSim("+al+")",300);
 if(al == 100){
   status.innerHTML = "100%";
   bar.value = 100;
   clearTimeout(sim);
   var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
   finalMessage.innerHTML = "Process is complete";
 }
}
var amountLoaded = 0;
progressBarSim(amountLoaded);
}
<script>
<button onclick="javascript:startProgress(); return false;">Start progress</button>
```